# Navigation wrapping up

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have a small navigation, responsive that don't work and I can't figure out why, it wraps up to the second line, but there is nothing in the CSS that actually sets a width so it shouldn't happen; [the url is here](http://www.vanessarc.com/newpage/index.php)

I tried setting different widths, paddings.. it sometimes seems to work but as soon as I play with the window it goes again as if I had changed nothing, so It keeps getting me lost.

Of course, my bad, I just wanted to show the visual problem for if some thought would occur.

The navigation I use is this one:

```css
.nav-wrapper {
  padding: 5% 0;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

#nav {
  /* container */
}

#nav>a {
  display: none;
}

#nav li {
  position: relative;
}


/* first level */

#nav>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#nav>ul>li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 2%;
  font-family: 'helvetica neue', arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: left;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}


/* second level */

#nav li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

#nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 40em) {
  /* 640 */
  #nav {
    position: relative;
  }
  #nav>a {}
  #nav:not( :target)>a:first-of-type,
  #nav:target>a:last-of-type {
    display: block;
  }
  /* first level */
  #nav>ul {
    height: auto;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  #nav>ul.active {
    display: block;
  }
  #nav>ul>li {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
  /* second level */
  #nav li ul {
    position: static;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class='nav-wrapper'>
    <div class='table'>
      <nav id="nav" role="navigation">
        <a href="#nav" title="Show navigation">Show navigation</a>
        <a href="#" title="Hide navigation">Hide navigation</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <!--Blog-->
          <li><a href="/">Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Web Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="graphicdesign.php">Graphic Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Resources</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant bits of HTML and CSS here so that future viewers can refer to the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to apply `overflow:hidden;` to the containing `ul`:

```
#nav > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden; /* Add this line */
}
```

When working with floated elements (`li` in your case) it's always better to set `overflow:hidden` to the container (parent). This rule forces the container to wrap around all of the children instead of having height of 0px and causing weird problems.

**EDIT:**
What seems to keep causing it is `<div class="table">` You've set the `display:table` on this div which causes it not to return to it's full width when making the screen wide again. Remove this rule and update the design to center the navigation in another way.

Comment: Thank you Yotam, but if I do that, it corrects it the first time, then it wraps down again...

Comment: taking another look hold on

Comment: I've edited - remove `display:table` from `.table` - it causes the div.table not to grow back to it's original size. Use a different approach for centering the navigation.

Comment: I already updated the design, and took the div out, and the style from the css, and what I was trying to do now was setting this in the css .nav ul { max-width: 90%; margin:0 auto; display: inline-block; overflow:hidden; } and .nav ul li { display: inline;} also, giving .nav-wrapper {text-align:center,} and this worked in other cases but some reason, it doesnt do anything with in this one.

Comment: I would suggest wrapping the `<ul>` width a `<div style="display:inline-block;">` and setting `#nav{text-align:center;}`.. this should do to the trick. It would be easier next time to create a jsFiddle so we can both work on it.

Comment: Facepalm! I forgot about jsFiddle... Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

So finally I got it to work, Thanks to Yotam Omer, I removed the display:table, and then wrapped it up in a div that I aligned with text-align:center, also removed the float:left on the li, and the max-width on the ul, and it worked perfectly. I explain it here for if this can help someone in the future. I paste the final Code.

```
<section>
<div class='nav-wrapper'>
    <nav id="nav" role="navigation">
        <a href="#nav" title="Show navigation">Show navigation</a>
        <a href="#" title="Hide navigation">Hide navigation</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li><!--Blog-->
            <li><a href="/">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Web Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="graphicdesign.php">Graphic Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Resources</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
</section>


.nav-wrapper{
padding: 5% 0;
text-align:center;
}

 #nav{
/* container */
}
#nav > a{
    display: none;
}
#nav li
{
    position: relative;
}

/* first level */

#nav > ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:inline-block;
}
    #nav > ul > li
    {
        display:inline;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 2%;
        font-family: 'helvetica neue', arial, sans-serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 0.8em;
    }

/* second level */

#nav li ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
    #nav li:hover ul
    {
        display: block;
    }

@media only screen and ( max-width: 40em ){/* 640 */

#nav{
    position: relative;
}
    #nav > a{
    }
    #nav:not( :target ) > a:first-of-type,
    #nav:target > a:last-of-type
    {
        display: block;
    }

/* first level */

#nav > ul{
    height: auto;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
    #nav > ul.active{
        display: block;
    }
    #nav > ul > li{
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }


/* second level */

    #nav li ul{
        position: static;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help. :)